# error after using imshow() in mac

Tags: python, opencv, macos-sierra

My code:

```
import cv2
import numpy
import matplotlib

img=cv2.imread('square1.png')
cv2.imshow('FRAME',img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tusharsharma/Desktop/image project/test1.py", line 5, in <module> cv2.imshow('FRAME',img)
cv2.error: /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:583:
error: (-2) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. 
If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, 
then re-run cmake or configure script in function cvShowImage
```

OS is macOS Sierra. I had installed OpenCV using homebrew for Python 3.

Comment: Please follow this [tutorial](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/15/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-osx/)

Comment: it is for python2 im currently working on python3 .

Comment: But the instructions would nearly be same.

Comment: @TusharSharma +1. Have exactly the same problem. Not sure why people downvoted you. Installing opencv has *never* been easy on any platform.

Comment: @ZdaR "But the instructions wold nearly be same" the most misleading and unhelpful comment I've seen for a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the main problem was with the configuration of build of OpenCv2 make sure you enter the correct part of your python libraries and Header files
for instance the following command will work for OpenCv for Python 3.6.1
`cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
 -D PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=$(which python3) \
 -D PYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR=$(python3 -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_inc; print(get_python_inc())") \
 -D PYTHON3_LIBRARY=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/config-3.4m/libpython3.4.dylib \
 -D PYTHON3_LIBRARIES=/Library/Frameworks/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin \
 -D PYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR=/Library/Frameworks1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/Headers \
 -D PYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH=$(python3 -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print(get_python_lib())") \
 -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
 -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON \
 -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules ..`

Answer (score 1):

You may check these tutorials for solving the problem on installing `OpenCV 3` for `Python 3` for `macOS`.

- [macOS: Install OpenCV 3 and Python 3.5](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/12/05/macos-install-opencv-3-and-python-3-5/)
- [Install OpenCV 3 on macOS with Homebrew (the easy way)](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/12/19/install-opencv-3-on-macos-with-homebrew-the-easy-way/)
- [Resolving macOS, OpenCV, and Homebrew install errors](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/05/15/resolving-macos-opencv-homebrew-install-errors/)

Hope this help.

Comment: installation part is done. imread() and all are working only the imshow() function the prob is occurring its asking for gtk but mac doent have it

Comment: Could you provide some more information how have you installed `OpenCV 3.2.0`? And which 'Python 3' version you are using?

Comment: i hv installed openCv 3.2.0 and python is 3.6.1

Comment: How have you installed it? What's the commands?  ... 2 questions

Comment: by this site http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/12/05/macos-install-opencv-3-and-python-3-5/#comment-426712

Comment: Try to install  GTK+ 2.x by this command `brew install gtk+`.

Comment: if i could show u screen shot then u could hv evaluted

Comment: Post as much as relevant info would ease the reviewers to understand your problem. You may update your question with additional info.

Comment: can you check the image i uploaded